# How is the ServiceStack "AllRoles" collection determined?

Tags: servicestack

Trying to enable the ServiceStack Studio User Management utility to more easily manage the various users that access our APIs.  It appears that to populate the roles dropdown, the User Management utility queries the following property:

[API_URL]/metadata/app.json -

```
{
   ...
   "allRoles":["Admin","Employee","Manager"]
   ...
}
```

But I don't see how ServiceStack determines the list of allRoles for a given IAuthRepository.

The only way I've been able to add a role to the allRoles collection is by adding a decoration to one of my database operations:

```
[ValidateHasRole("ZZZ")]
```

Are there other ways to inform an IAuthRepository of what roles to expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purposes of determining the pre-populated list of Roles in [ServiceStack Studio](https://docs.servicestack.net/studio), ServiceStack shows all Roles defined within your Application, e.g. via the `[ValidateHasRole]` [Declarative Type Validator](https://docs.servicestack.net/declarative-validation#type-validators) or the `[RequiredRole*]` [Authentication attributes](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#requiredrole-and-requiredpermission-attributes).